# Tutorial Install Parse push notification with ionic 2 and ionic 3

Tags: typescript, parse-platform, push-notification, ionic2, ionic3

1.You Create new project.
Command>`ionic start <nameproject> <type> --v2`

2.You open file config.xml in new project.

```
<preference name="ParseAppId" value="APPLICATION_ID" />
<preference name="ParseServerUrl" value="You_URL_Parse_Server" />
<preference name="ParseGcmSenderId" value="You_Gcm_ID" />
<preference name="ParseMultiNotifications" value="true" />
<preference name="ParseAutoRegistration" value="false" />
<preference name="ParseNotificationIcon" value="icon" />
```

3.You add parse-push-plugin plugin.
Command>cordova plugin add https://github.com/taivo/parse-push-plugin --save

4.You Open app.component.ts file  form src/app/app.component.ts
4.1 You add variable > `declare var ParsePushPlugin: any;`
4.2 You new function in constractor in file app.component.ts

```
ParsePushPlugin.getInstallationId(function (id) {
    ParsePushPlugin.on('receivePN', function (pn) {
        alert(pn.alert);
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What exactly is your question? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Are you trying to ask and answer a question?

Comment: Your question needs to follow [ask] rules and your answer should be in the answer section.

Comment: This might have deserved to be put in the StackOverflow documentation, but the project has been shut down.

Comment: Hi Steve, I use parse via back4app and I've already used the notification in a project using ionic 1. I'm starting a new project with parse and I'm going down if I use ionic 1 or 3, what did you post it works?

Comment: I'am sorry ,This not question. but it work with me ,My want share tutorial install Parse push notification with ionic 2 and ionic 3.

.